# GitLab CI custom variable not recognized in rules

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When defining a variable in the `variables` block which uses a predefined CI variable, it cannot be referenced in the `rules` blocks. Here, **only job_1** gets executed:

```
variables:
  PRODUCTION_BRANCH: $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

stages:
  - stage_1

job_1:
  stage: stage_1
  script:
    - export
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'

job_2:
  stage: stage_1
  script:
    - export
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $PRODUCTION_BRANCH'
```

But when hardcoding the value for `PRODUCTION_BRANCH` it works as expected. Here, **both jobs** get executed:

```
variables:
  PRODUCTION_BRANCH: "master"

stages:
  - stage_1

job_1:
  stage: stage_1
  script:
    - export
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'

job_2:
  stage: stage_1
  script:
    - export
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $PRODUCTION_BRANCH'
```

When looking into the output of the jobs (since `export` logs the env-variables), in both cases there is the variable `PRODUCTION_BRANCH` with the correct value `master`.
Why does it behave like that and is there a fix / workaround?

Comment: What version are you using? Looks like similar issues are resolved as of 13.6: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/206929 & https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/34272 and in 13.7: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/209864 . This one is still open though: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35315

Comment: @Arty-chan I'm running version 13.5.3. Seems like the last issue relates to mine

Comment: [user1452736](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1452736) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68680222) saying "it's maybe because on your gitlab instance disabled this feature [https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#enabling-the-nested-variable-expansion-feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#enabling-the-nested-variable-expansion-feature)"

Answer (score 5):

**Update 2022-09:**

It appears that gitlab has fixed some issues related to this.

I haven't had a chance to re-test yet whether this is completely resolved issue or if there are still some pitfalls to be aware of.

Just be aware that the below answer may no longer be correct/current.

---

gitlab does not do variable expansion of the `variables` section when evaluating the yaml and determining what to run.  Variable interpolation does work within the runner though.

So you have to be careful if you are using variable interpolation when defining custom variables.  Are they for gitlab conditions (won't work) or are they for use in runner only (after gitlab has decided to run the job...this works)?

This is confusing and I couldn't find any warning/reference to this high-probability pitfall in the docs...but maybe I missed it.

So in your `if:` you can use

- `$CI_*` variables

  - ([except for a few ENVIRONMENT ones](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#gitlab-ciyml-file) ...see description column for `rules` in the linked where variables can be used table.)
- custom variables you have defined globally or within a job

  - ```yaml
    variables:
        PRODUCTION_BRANCH: "main"
    ```

But if your `if:` depends on custom variables (ie `$PRODUCTION_BRANCH`) that themselves require variable interpolation...

```yaml
variables:
    PRODUCTION_BRANCH: $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

...it won't work.  `$PRODUCTION_BRANCH` will have the value you expect within the RUNNER (once the job is started) but gitlab doesn't do the interpolation when parsing the yaml and deciding which jobs to run.

In your case, simplest thing is just to use the `$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` variable directly in your `if:`.

## Example `.gitlab-ci.yml` demonstrating this...

You can drop this in a new empty repo.  Just update `REPO_NAMESPACE`, `REPO_NAME` and `ONLY_DEPLOY_BRANCH` to match the current repo/branch.

jobs:

- `debug` - runs and outputs vars showing all the values you expect (in a runner context)
- `deploy1` - runs
- `deploy2` - does **not** run
- `deploy3` - runs (shows the variables are definitely not interpolated on the gitlab side).

```yaml
variables:
  REPO_NAMESPACE: "my-group/my-subgroup"
  REPO_NAME: "my-project"
  ONLY_DEPLOY_BRANCH: "main"
  ONLY_DEPLOY_FROM: "${REPO_NAMESPACE}/${REPO_NAME}"
  ONLY_DEPLOY_FROM2: "my-group/my-subgroup/my-project"



stages:
  - debug
  - deploy

# this runs
# variables all have expected values (in runner scope) and you would expect both deploy* jobs to run
debug:
  stage: debug
  script:
    - export  

# this runs
deploy1:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine:latest
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PROJECT_PATH == $ONLY_DEPLOY_FROM2 && $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG == $ONLY_DEPLOY_BRANCH
      when: always
  script:
    - echo "Hello world!"

# this doesn't run.  
# Only difference to deploy1 job is using $ONLY_DEPLOY_FROM instead of $ONLY_DEPLOY_FROM2
# conclusion... gitlab must not do variable expansion of the variables section when determining which jobs run.
deploy2:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine:latest
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PROJECT_PATH == $ONLY_DEPLOY_FROM && $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG == $ONLY_DEPLOY_BRANCH
      when: always
  script:
    - echo "Hello world!"

# this runs which confirms that $ONLY_DEPLOY_FROM has not had CI variables replaced.
deploy3:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine:latest
  rules:
    - if: $ONLY_DEPLOY_FROM == "$REPO_NAMESPACE/${REPO_NAME}" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG == $ONLY_DEPLOY_BRANCH
      when: always
  script:
    - echo "Hello world!"
```

You can use the ci linter (`https://gitlab.com/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}/-/ci/lint`) to play with this.  It is a good tool in general for troubleshooting problems without making a thousand commits in a row to .gitlab-ci.yml and burning through shared runner hours.

## Open issue

Gitlab has ~40k open issues.  Here are the relevant tickets though...

[Supporting variable expansion for runner](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1809#variable-expansion-scenarios-not-covered-with-this-feature) (resolved)
[Supporting the gitlab side variable expansion](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/293674)  -- this problem.  <s>still open issue.</s> - closed Apr 27, 2022

Comment: This is a great pitfall and enormously limits the usage of rules against custom only/except job config. Great answer !!!

Answer (score 1):

Just put the value in quotes:

```
variables:
  PRODUCTION_BRANCH: "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH"
```